# C# Outlook get public Appointments of other users by using EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, appointment

I'm currently trying to retrieve public Appointments of a users Calendar in Outlook (with Exchange2013) to a DataSet to be displayed later on.
Here's the relevant code so far:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.AutodiscoverUrl("mail@mycompany.com", RedirectionCallback);
DateTime reportDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(reportDate.Year, reportDate.Month, reportDate.Day, 0, 0, 1);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddHours(23);
endDate = endDate.AddMinutes(59);
CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "somemail@mycompany.com"));
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);
cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Location);

// get appointment collection
FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);

// transfer to DataSet
DataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Clear();
int i = 0;
foreach (Appointment a in appointments) {
    DataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(
        i++.ToString(),
        a.Subject.ToString(),
        a.Start.ToString(),
        a.End.ToString(),
        a.Location.ToString());
}
```

An exception is being shown in the Line

> CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "somemail@mycompany.com"));

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Or is there even a completely other way on how to approach my problem?

Comment: What is the exception? (why do I even have to ask for you to provide that?)

Comment: sorry, first post ever :) There is no specific exception, should have told you. It just says there was an exception of type "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll" which wasn't handled

Comment: You say "there is no specific exception" and then you go on to say "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll".... that sounds pretty specific to me.  What is the exception message?

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm used to getting more specific messages than this. Now I viewed the actual exception message (thanks for the tip) - it says "The Mailbox that was requested doesn't support the specified RequestServerVersion". May this have something to do with my _ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_ declaration?

Comment: How do you define "more specific"?  There is no degree of specificity associated with an exception -- i.e. one exception cannot be "more specific" than another exception -- save for that which could be applied through class derivation.  So, you hadn't even checked the exception message before posting this question?  I think the message you provided is pretty clear -- did you try googling that message?

Comment: Like I already said, I'm sorry, that's my first post. I'll provide more neccessary information directly in the beginning. I changed the _ExchangeVersion_ to 2010, right now I receive the message _"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."_.
I see that I do not have access to view the private appointments and Mails of another's mailbox, but since I only want to view his public appointments I can't see why I'd need authentication for that? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The account which you are using to connect tho the exchange server doesn't have permission to read the mailbox of somemail@mycompany.com. Try to get a super user privilege for the account. Hope this is useful.